# Function with dependent preset arguments

Tags: python

Please consider simple function:

```
def fun(x, y, param1=10, param2=param1/3):
    do something
```

Where `param1` and `param2` should not be required but can be set by user. If `param2` is not set, value is dependant on `param1` in some way.

Above example will raise `NameError: name 'param1' is not defined`

Is there a way to do this kind of assignment in Python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is to emulate this inside the function:

```
def fun(x, y, param1=10, param2=None):
    if param2 is None:
        param2 = param1/3
    # do something
```

If `param2=None` is a valid input into `fun()`, the following might be a better alternative:

```
default = object()

def fun(x, y, param1=10, param2=default):
    if param2 is default:
        param2 = param1 / 3
    # do something
```

(Having been looking at this second example for a few minutes, I actually quite like the `is default` syntax.)

The reason the original version doesn't work is that default values are computed and bound at the function definition time. This means that you can't have a default that's dependent on something that's not known until the function is called (in your case, the value of `param1`).

Comment: `default` might be misleading, `not_set` could be a better name. It is not clear (to me) at a glance that `default` is not the default value itself but a placeholder signaling that a default value for `param2` should be used.