# Using the length of a parameter array as the default value of another parameter of the same function

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my first time asking a question in SO, so if I'm somehow not doing it properly don't hesitate to edit it or ask me to modify it.

I think my question is kind of general, so I'm quite surprised for not having found any previous one related to this topic. If I missed it and this question is duplicated, I'll be very grateful if you could provide a link to where it was already answered.

Imagine I need to implement a function with (at least) three parameters: an array `a`, a `start` index and an `end` index. If not provided, the `start` parameter should refer to the first position of the array (`start = 0`), while the `end` parameter should be set to the last position (`end = len(a) - 1`). Obviously, the definition:

```python
def function(a, start = 0, end = (len(a) - 1)):
    #do_something
    pass
```

does not work, leading to an exception (`NameError: name 'a' is not defined`). There are some workarounds, such as using `end = -1` or `end = None`, and conditionally assign it to `len(a) - 1` if needed inside the body of the function:

```python
def function(a, start = 0, end = -1):
    end = end if end != -1 else (len(a) -1)
    #do_something
```

but I have the feeling that there should be a more "pythonic" way of dealing with such situations, not only with the length of an array but with any parameter whose default value is a function of another (non optional) parameter. How would you deal with a situation like that? Is the conditional assignment the best option?

Thanks!

Comment: Using the `def function(a, start=0, end=None):` solution seems the most obvious to me as in Python you do not use `int`s with "weird" value for a different meaning - because Python like explicit over implicit. `None` has the exact meaning you're looking for *i.e.* no value was specified. It also allows you for a more explicit and shorter assignment `end = end or len(a)`

Comment: @bvidal `end = end or len(a)` will assign `len(a)` to `end` if `end` is `0`. One would need to do `end = end if end is not None else len(a)`.

Comment: @DanD. thanks I overlooked this case

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function with dependent preset arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900284/function-with-dependent-preset-arguments)

Comment: @bvidal Thanks! In my example I was using ```-1``` instead of ```None``` as in lists ```a[-1] == a[len(a) - 1]```, but I agree that ```None``` looks more appropiate

Comment: Every once in a while there are cases like this in code where I feel like saying, 'wouldn't it be cool if it were possible to do x'. Your question raises an interesting domain. I have no idea personally whether this something that can be built into the language, but it looks nice and would save on code that would otherwise be irrelevant to the function's main logic.

Comment: @sepulchered Thanks! It seems that I missed that question! It provides a really good suggestion!!!

Comment: @Eithos Yes, it just "feels" natural.. It's a pity that it is not allowed hehe

Comment: I disagree that it feels natural. The whole concept of Python's default parameter values is that they are calculated **exactly once**, at function-definition time. (In fact, this is what catches so many people out when they want to set the default to an empty list or other mutable value.) What you are asking for is a value which is calculated not at function-definition time but at function-run time; and putting that in the function signature is counter to Python's design. The idiomatic way to handle run-time defaults is to calculate them **inside** the function.

Comment: @JohnY I agree with you, as it stands it could not mesh naturally with Python's mechanisms (as you eloquently put it). However, that's not really the point. It's more of, 'What _if_ Python _could_ be modelled in such a way that a behaviour like this could work without compromising the language'. Obviously it's idiomatic to do it inside the function because that's the only natural way to do it in Python, not because (IMO) it's the best way from a design point-of-view. If it worked, I have a feeling the Zen of Python would be more inclined to support this alternative form or allow both, somehow.

Comment: @franrodalg I've posted a solution of my own to your question. I don't say you should do it this way (because I admit it's not idiomatic and the side-effects could very well confuse other programmers)... but it's very close to what you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by @NPE in [Function with dependent preset arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900284/function-with-dependent-preset-arguments), an alternative to using `-1` or (better) `None` as sentinel values is using an object (a named object?) which can be used even if `None` is a valid value of the function. For example:

```python
default = object()

def function(a, start = 0, end = default):
    if end is default: end = (len(a) - 1)
    return start, end
```

allows a call like: `function([1,2,3,4])` which returns `(0, 3)`

I personally find this solution quite convenient, at least for my own purpose

*Edit:* Maybe the code is even more readable if we use `last` instead of `default`:

```python
last = object()

def function(a, start = 0, end = last):
    if end is last: end = (len(a) - 1)
    return start, end
```

Comment: To me, the function is decidedly *less* readable if you use `last`. What does "last" mean here? Do you mean the last position of `a`? Well, that's already indicated by the name of the parameter, `end`. If I were casually reading your code, I would guess that `last` is something to save the value from the last call. In other words, if your function is called without `end`, then use the previous value of `end`. I think `default` communicates the intention much better. Another descriptive choice would be `sentinel`.

Answer (score 9):

Using a sentinel value such as `None` is typical:

```
def func(a, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = # whatever
    # do stuff
```

---

However, for your actual use case, there's already a builtin way to do this that fits in with the way Python does start/stop/step - which makes your function provide a consistent interface as to the way builtins/other libraries work:

```
def func(a, *args):
    slc = slice(*args)
    for el in a[slc]:
        print(el)
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice

---

If you only want to support start/end in that order, then (note that `None` effectively means *until* `len(a)` when used as *end* or `0` when used as *start*):

```
def func(a, start=0, end=None):
    return a[start:end]
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about the ```slice``` method, but anyway it does not cover my needs, as the particular values of ```start``` and ```end``` are needed. I guess the conditional assignment is the best solution. I was considering ```-1``` as an option as it refers to the last element of a list (```a[-1] == a[len(a) - 1]```, but probably ```None``` is a more elegant solution

Comment: @franrodalg you can use `None` for both start and end... - that way you can use `func(a)` (which will just be the whole lot), or `func(a, end=5)` first 5, or `func(a, 2)` from 2 onwards... or `func(a, 2, 6)` etc...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, functions can't be executed in the parameter list, you can pass along functions through the parameters but not their output.

```
def function(a, start = 0):
    end = len(a)
```

Comment: I already had that impression, but I was wondering if there was any built-in way to deal with such situations.. which it seems it doesn't exist hehe.

Your code solution does not help much, as in my case (and in the general case too) ```end``` can take any value, not just ```len(a)```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your definition of an array or the premise of your problem, but to my understanding you are trying get end to be assigned to the length of a. If so, just declare end out side the arguments. Like so:

```
def function(a, start=0):
    end=len(a)
```

Or do the conditional like you said:

```
def function(a, start=0, end=False):
    if not end:
        end = len(a)
```

Or simply declare the end variable before calling the function and pass it in the arguments!
Not sure if that answered your question, but hope it helped lol!

Answer (score 0):

This has to be the hackiest code I've ever written. I think it comes close to what you were asking for (another alternative I came up with was using a lambda inside the function definition, but it takes a bit too much room to be pretty IMO):

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

class defaultArguments(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lazyArgs = []

    def initialize(self, func):

        lazyArgs, self.lazyArgs = self.lazyArgs, []

        @wraps(func)
        def functionWrapper(*args, **kw):

            if lazyArgs:
                
                argNames, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)[::3]
                argValues = list(args) + [
                    kw[y] if y in kw else defaults[x]
                    for x,y in enumerate(argNames[len(args):])
                ]

                oldGlobals = {}
                for n,v in zip(argNames, argValues):

                    try:
                        oldGlobals[n] = globals()[n]
                    except:
                        oldGlobals[n] = None

                    if v not in lazyArgs:
                        globals()[n] = v
                    else:
                        globals()[n] = kw[n] = eval(v)

                for o,v in oldGlobals.items(): globals()[o] = v

            return func(*args, **kw)

        return functionWrapper

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.lazyArgs.append(x)
        return x
```

**Using it**:

```
d = defaultArguments()

@d.initialize
def function1(a, start=d('a[-1]'), end=d('len(a)-1')):
    print a, start, end


function1([1,2,8])
>>> [1, 2, 8] 8 2

function1([1,2,8,10], end=1)
>>> [1, 2, 8, 10] 10 1


@d.initialize
def function2(a, b, c, start=d('a*b*c'), end=d('a+b+c+start')):
    print a, start, end

function2(2,4,6)
>>> 2 48 60
# Notice that `end` does take the calculated value of `start` into 
# account. The logic here is based on what you'd expect to happen
# with normal assignment if the names were each assigned a value 
# sequentially: a is evaluated, then b, then c, etc...
```

I do feel guilty for doing this, especially with the way I resorted to using globals and other cheats. However, I think it works as you requested.

*Unfortunately*, you do have to write extra stuff (using a decorator and having to wrap keyword values in `d('')` ), but that was inevitable as Python doesn't support this natively.

#### Edit:

I worked on the sugary part of the syntax a bit. Shortened it down to a simple decorator function.

```
def initArgs(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def functionWrapper(*args, **kw):

        argNames, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)[::3]

        for k in kw:
            for i in argNames:
                if k != i and ('_' + k) == i:
                    kw['_' + k] = kw[k]
                    del kw[k]

        argValues = list(args) + [
            kw[y] if y in kw else defaults[x]
            for x,y in enumerate(argNames[len(args):])
        ]

        oldGlobals = {}
        for n,v in zip(argNames, argValues):

            try:
                oldGlobals[n] = globals()[n]
            except:
                oldGlobals[n] = None

            if not n.startswith('_') or n in kw:
                globals()[n] = v
            else:
                globals()[n] = kw[n] = eval(v)

        for o,v in oldGlobals.items(): globals()[o] = v

        return func(*args, **kw)

    return functionWrapper
```

**To use it:**

```
# When using initArgs, the strings associated with the keyword arguments will
# get eval'd only if the name is preceded with an underscore(`_`). It's a 
# bit strange and unpythonic for part of a name to have side effects, but then
# again name mangling works with double underscores (`__`) before methods.

# Example: 

@initArgs
def function1(a, _start='a[-1]', _end='len(a)-1'):
    print a, _start, _end

function1([1,2,8,10])
>>> [1, 2, 8, 10] 10 3

# Removing underscore (`_`) from start
@initArgs
def function2(a, start='a[-1]', _end='len(a)-1'):
    print a, start, _end

function1([1,2,8,10])
>>> [1, 2, 8, 10] 'a[-1]' 3

# Outputs a string normally.
```

In the caller's frame, the arguments `start` and `end` can used with or without their underscores, so changing their names in the function definition at a later point wouldn't affect the caller. The only exception is within the function itself, where removing an underscore(`_`) would require doing the same everywhere else inside.