# How to pass the the output of len() as a default value for a function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that can print out a list and depending on the arguments the function will print the values up to the selected list length.

However, `NameError: name 'data_list' is not defined`. I am assuming it's referring to the `data_list` variable within `len()`.

I understand I can set `len(data_list)` as a variable outside the function but I would like all contained within.

The expected outcome is to be able to have the default `list_length` be equal to the length of the `data_list` used as the input argument.

```
def function(data_list, list_length = len(data_list)):
    print(data_list[0:list_length+1])
```

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: It can't be done. You'll have to give it a default value of something like `None` then in the function check it's value making it the length of `data_list` if it is `None`.

Comment: Thanks! setting list_length = None solved the issue.

Comment: More information on the solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212364/using-the-length-of-a-parameter-array-as-the-default-value-of-another-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default value of None:

```
>>> def f(a, length=None):
...     return a[:length]

>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> f(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> f(a,4)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: See [Note 4](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) of the Common Sequence Operations in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

1). Do not use `list_length = len(data_list)` as an argument.

2). Instead of this assign `list_length` inside of function.

```
def function(data_list):
    list_length = len(data_list)
    if list_length >= 10:
        print(data_list[0:list_length+1])
    else:
        print("Your data_list is less than 10. ")
```

Comment: I would like the user to be able to set restrictions on how much of the data_list is to be passed through.

Comment: @NathanThomas You can use `if-else` condition to set a restriction on the length of data_list. I have modified my code you can see it. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it would be recommended in this case, but using a decorator would do it.

```
def change_args(f):
    def wrapper(arg1, list_length=None):
        if list_length is None:
            return f(arg1, list_length=len(arg1))
        else:
            return f(arg1, list_length=list_length)
    return wrapper

@change_args
def function(data_list, list_length=None):
    print(data_list[0:list_length])
```

Then it works as you expect:

```
>>> function([1,2,3])
[1,2,3]
>>> function([1,2,3],list_length=2)
[1,2]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def function(data_list):
    list_length = len(data_list)
    print(data_list[0:list_length+1])
```

Will this work for you?

Comment: OP wants a `list_length ` parameter with a default value so the caller can specify something less than the `data_list`'s length. If no argument given then the whole list is *selected*